# Please give feed back on my proof that $S$ must be a basis for $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $S$ be a maximal linearly independent subset of a finite vector
space $V$. That is, $S$ has the property that if a vector not in $S$
is adjoined to $S$, then the new set will no longer be linearly
independent. Prove that $S$ must be a basis for $V$.

Proof:

We have $S$={$v_1...v_n$}$⊆V$, and because $S$ is linearly independent, there scalars $c_1...c_n$ must all zero if $c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n=0$

Let $v_{n+1}∈V$. by the problem statement, the set {$v_1...v_n, v_{n+1}$} is linearly dependent, so we can write $c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n+c_{n+1}v_{n+1}=0$ such that $c_1...c_n, c_{n+1}$ are not all $0$.

If $c_{n+1}=0$ then we have $c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n=0$ and because {${v_1,\ldots,v_n}$} is linearly independent, $c_1...c_n$ must all be $0$, which contradicts the fact that $c_1...c_n, c_{n+1}$ are not all $0$, so $c_{n+1}≠0$.

So we can write $v_{n+1}=(c_1/-c_{n+1})v_1+...+(c_n/-c_{n+1})v_n$.

Now, $v_{n+1}$ is an arbitrary element of $V$, so $SPAN${$v_1...v_n$}=$V$

So, $S$ must be a basis for $V$.

Comment: In the first line you're assuming $S$ is finite, but that isn't given (and it need not be true).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly correct, but you made a mistake when you wrote that, if $c_{n+1}=0$, then we have $c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n=0$, where $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ must all be $0$, which contradicts the fact that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_{n+1}\}$ is linearly dependent. There is no contradiction between $c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n=0$ and the fact that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_{n+1}\}$ is linearly dependent. The reason why we cannot have $c_{n+1}=0$ is that because then $c_1v_1+\cdots+c_nv_n=0$ which would imply (since $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent) that $c_1=\cdots=c_n=0$. But $c_{n+1}=0$ too and we are assuming that not all $c_k$'s are equal to $0$.

Comment: I still don't understand how what I have written is different.

Comment: in the line I say If $c_{n+1}=0$ then we have $c_1v_1+...+c_nv_n=0$ where $c_1...c_n$ must all be $0$, which contradicts the fact that {$v_1...v_n, v_{n+1}$} is linearly dependent, so $c_{n+1}≠0$. How is that different than saying there is a condraction between $c_1...c_{n+1}$ all being $0$ and {$v_1,…,v_n,v_{n+1}$} being linearly dependent.

Comment: Simply because there is **no contradiction at all** between every $c_k=0$ and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_{n+1}\}$ being linearly dependent.

Comment: For instance, $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$ are linearly dependent elements of $\Bbb R^2$ and you ave $0\times(1,0)+0\times(2,0)=(0,0)$.

Comment: but don't I show that every $c_k$ has to be $0$ to satisfy the equality?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think I understand your point now. I edited my post and  replaced {$v_1...v_n, v_{n+1}$} is linearly dependent with $c_1...c_n, c_{n+1}$ are not all $0$. Is this the only thing that needed changed?

Comment: The assertion “$\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_{n+1}\}$ is linearly dependent with $c_1,\ldots,c_n,c_{n+1}$ are not all $0$” makes no sense.

Comment: if a set in linearly dependent then there exists a linear combination whose scalars are not all 0. so i think it does make sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115717/discussion-between-bfff-and-jose-carlos-santos).